# If then statement to evaluate combo box and open userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to have a user select a form from a combo box, based on the selection, opening the associated userform and input text from textbox1 into textbox1 in the newly opened user form. I have tried select case and if then statements with no luck. Help please

```
Private Sub PrintSheet_Click()
Dim calltype As Variant
calltype = ComboBox1.Value

If calltype = "fire" Then
    NewRunUserForm.Show
    PrintUserForm.TextBox1.Value = NewRunUserForm.TextBox1.Value
    ElseIf calltype = "accident" Then
    AccidentUserForm.Show
    PrintUserForm.TextBox1.Value = AccidentUserForm.TextBox1.Value

    ElseIf calltype = "training" Then
    TrainingUserForm.Show
    PrintUserForm.TextBox1.Value = TrainingUserForm.TextBox1.Value

    ElseIf calltype = "meeting" Then
    MeetingUserForm.Show
    PrintUserForm.TextBox1.Value = MeetingUserForm.TextBox1.Value


End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried changing calltype as long which didn't seem to work either.
When I click the command button, nothing happens. Above is the code I have most recently tried. I am wanting a userform associated with the combox selection to .show.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve]

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: *When I click the command button, nothing happens* - so the handler doesn't run at all? Did you try putting a breakpoint on the `calltype = ComboBox1.Value` instruction to see if its value is what you assume it's going to be?

Comment: Is the actual runtime value of `calltype` all-lowercase? This would probably be a bit more elegant in a `Select Case ComboBox1.Value` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will at least tell you whats the value selected in combo box. Also, converted values to lower case while checking for `If` condition.

```
Private Sub PrintSheet_Click()
  Dim calltype As Variant
  calltype = ComboBox1.Value

  MsgBox "Value in ComboBox1: [" & CStr(calltype) & "]" 'remove this statement it later
  If LCase$(calltype) = "fire" Then
    NewRunUserForm.Show
    PrintUserForm.TextBox1.Value = NewRunUserForm.TextBox1.Value
  ElseIf LCase$(calltype) = "accident" Then
    AccidentUserForm.Show
    PrintUserForm.TextBox1.Value = AccidentUserForm.TextBox1.Value

  ElseIf LCase$(calltype) = "training" Then
    TrainingUserForm.Show
    PrintUserForm.TextBox1.Value = TrainingUserForm.TextBox1.Value

  ElseIf LCase$(calltype) = "meeting" Then
    MeetingUserForm.Show
    PrintUserForm.TextBox1.Value = MeetingUserForm.TextBox1.Value
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the open form is "Me". Your Combobox would be Me.ComboBox1, but the Me designation can be omitted for the current form. Now you have to create another form object. In your code you named these forms, but you didn't declare them. In the code below I gave shorter names to these forms and then declared them.

> Private Sub PrintSheet_Click()
>
> ```
> Dim calltype As String
> Dim SubForm As Object
>
> calltype = ComboBox1.Value
>
> Select Case calltype
>     Case "accident"
>         Set SubForm = New FrmAccident
>     Case "fire"
>         Set SubForm = New FrmFire
>     Case "meeting"
>     Case "training"
> End Select
>
> With SubForm
>     .TextBox1.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
>     .Show
> End With
> ```
>
> End Sub

The UserForm object "SubForm" is declared as an object for late binding. Then, depending upon the selection in the combobox one of the existing forms is assigned to the SubForm object.
Finally, the Textbox1 in Subform (whichever one it is) is assigned the value of Textbox1 from the current form, which is "Me", and the subform is shown. You could add code like Me.Hide at that point to let the Me form temporarily disappear while the Subform is open and then show it again when you are done with the Subform.